# how to create no of radio button groups dynamically in python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create no of groups of radio button in python tkinter.

There is error in creating different no of StringVar variables dynamically

```
from tkinter import *
def sel():
    selection =  str(var.get())
    label.config(text = selection)

root = Tk()
var = StringVar()
label = Label(root)
label.pack()
for i in range(0,4):
   var[i] = StringVar()
   R1 = Radiobutton(root, text="Bad", variable=var[i],value="bad",command=sel)
   R1.select()
   label.config(text=var.get())
   R1.pack()
   R2 = Radiobutton(root, text="No Effect", variable=var[i],value="noeffect",command=sel)
   R2.pack()
   R3 = Radiobutton(root, text="Good", variable=var[i], value="good",command=sel)
   R3.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: And the error you have?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\T!t@ns\Desktop\Project started\try.py", line 11, in <module>
    var[i] = StringVar()
TypeError: 'StringVar' object does not support item assignment

Comment: var[i] = StringVar()
TypeError: 'StringVar' object does not support item assignment

Comment: @sqluser can u provide me the solution

Answer (score 1):

I am certainly not the most expert person in python, but you have a problem that you are declaring `var = StringVar()` and then in your loop you are trying to use it as e.g. a dictionary or something by doing `var[i] = StringVar()` which python rightfully complains about. You could do `var = {}` i.e. create an empty dictionary and then in the loop put `StringVar`s in it. Also I think you `sel` method needs `var[i]` rather than `var` in it.

Comment: @MayurRastogi in case you found the solution yourself, you should post it as an answer and accept it so that people can see that your problem is solved. In case my answer helped you resolve your issue, you could consider accepting it

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *
def sel():
   selection =  str(var[0].get())
   label.config(text = selection)

root = Tk()
var={}
label = Label(root)
label.pack()
for i in range(0,4):  
   var[i] = StringVar()
   R1 = Radiobutton(root, text="Bad", variable=var[i], value="bad",command=sel)
   R1.select()
   label.config(text=var[i].get())
   R1.pack()
   R2 = Radiobutton(root, text="No Effect", variable=var[i], value="no effect",command=sel)
   R2.pack()
   R3 = Radiobutton(root, text="Good", variable=var[i], value="good",command=sel)
   R3.pack()

root.mainloop()
```